# can not link my nodejs server with my angular app

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I tried to upload an image using angular and nodejs(server-side), but when I want to view the web page I can not get anything.
here is my browser output
[image]
here is my server.js code

```
// server.js
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express();

const DIR = './uploads';
 
let storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, DIR);
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.' + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});
let upload = multer({storage: storage});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
 
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});
 
app.get('/api', function (req, res) {
  res.end('file catcher example');
});
 
app.post('/api/upload',upload.single('photo'), function (req, res) {
    if (!req.file) {
        console.log("No file received");
        return res.send({
          success: false
        });
    
      } else {
        console.log('file received');
        return res.send({
          success: true
        })
      }
});
 
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
 
app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log('Node.js server is running on port'+ PORT);
});
```

this is my app.component.html code

```
<div class="container">
  <input type="file" name="photo" ng2FileSelect  />
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-s" 
    (click)="uploader.uploadAll()" 
    [disabled]="!uploader.getNotUploadedItems().length" >
        Upload an Image
  </button>
</div>
```

this is my app.component.ts code

```
// app.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {  FileUploader, FileSelectDirective } from 'ng2-file-upload/';

const URL = 'http://localhost:4000/api/upload';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'ng8fileupload';
  public uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({ url: URL, itemAlias: 'photo' });
  ngOnInit() {
    this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (file) => { file.withCredentials = false; };
    this.uploader.onCompleteItem = (item: any, response: any, status: any, headers: any) => {
         console.log('ImageUpload:uploaded:', item, status, response);
         alert('File uploaded successfully');
    };
 }
}
```

and finally, this is my app.module.ts code

```
// app.module.ts

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FileSelectDirective } from 'ng2-file-upload';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Fix your import statement by removing the trailing `/`:

`import {  FileUploader, FileSelectDirective } from 'ng2-file-upload';`

Also in future, please add any errors that are produced by the Angular dev server to your post.

Comment: I still can not get anything, I think there is a problem on the root of my angular project